# Как правильно использовать location.href

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```css
#outerdiv {
  width: 384px;
  height: 411px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#inner_iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -350px;
  left: -450px;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='outerdiv'>
  <iframe src="http://sbr-test.elt-poisk.com/" scrolling="no" id="inner_iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Как использовать location.href чтобы при смене адреса (после нажатия батона) iframe закрывался, а страница на которую переводила кнопка открывалась в текущей вкладке (где был iframe)

Comment: это делается либо меткой target на теге А, либа фейковым ликом fakeLink, которому присваивается target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На js так

```
  <iframe onload="load1_handler()" id="inner_iframe" src="2.htm" width=100 height=100 > </iframe>
  <script>
  function navigate( url, target ) {
       var fakeLink = document.createElement("a");
       if (typeof(fakeLink.click)=="undefined"){
          location.href =  id; 
         } else {
         fakeLink.href =  url; 
         if (target) fakeLink.target = target;
         document.body.appendChild(fakeLink);
         fakeLink.click();
         }
    }
// далее обработчик фрейма
var rdy_cnt = 0;
function load1_handler(){
if (rdy_cnt++ == 0) return;
navigate("http://sbr-test.elt-poisk.com","_top");
}
```

Событие t1 можно попробовать повесить не на таймер, а там на onchange или on... другое событие фрейма. Я такую задачу не делал, но код сработает.

target в вашем случае "_top", почитать про target можно тут http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_a_target.asp

2. html Если обычная ссылка можно обойтись `<a href=url target=_top>метка</a>` нужно внутри страницы
3. тег base `<base target=_top><iframe/></base>`
   он задает как должны работать ссылки на странице.
   источник http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Не могу понять, а как привязать это к iframe?

Comment: <code><base target=_top><iframe src="http://sbr-test.elt-poisk.com/" scrolling="no" id="inner_iframe"></iframe></base></code> Попробовал так, но все равно после логина и пароля и щелчка по "Войти" платформа открывается в маленьком окошке iframe`а @nick_n_a

Comment: Похоже все три нужно применять внутри фрейма, а можно ли поменять снаружи - не знаю, но как вы тогда использовали location.href?

Comment: К сожалению я не имею доступа к коду к тому что во фрейме. Кстати. Вы мне и дали наводку на это действие в предыдущих вопросах: "Максимум что может сделать родительский фрейм - следить за location.href дочки, когда будет сделан переход на страницу по кнопке "войти" - дочка сменит url, что и можно отловить. – nick_n_a 3 часа назад". Как раз и хотел уточнить, как это вообще делается? На всякий случай вот мой CodePen где все манипуляции провожу: http://codepen.io/hlopka/pen/rLEgRm

Comment: Я попробывал у себя минимальный пример - поправил ответ. Понятно что недостаток - задержка на таймере.

Comment: Можете по codepen проверить? Почему то автоматически начинает пустышки (blank-page) открывать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44630/discussion-between--and-nick-n-a).

Comment: Так не получилось же(