# Переход на другую страницу по нажатию на блок

Tags: javascript, html

Как при нажатии по `HTML`-блоку перейти на другую страницу? Не используя тег `<a>`.

Comment: А что мешает сделать ссылку тегом a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну из `div` ссылку вы сделать не сможете, но можно привязать `onclick` к нужному блоку и делать переход как по ссылке следующим образом:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://yoursite.com';">Content</div>
```

### Пример:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:hover {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="location.href='https://ru.stackoverflow.com';">Redirect to another site</div>
```

Если у вас не срабатывает корректно `onClick` в некоторых браузерах, то добавьте `javascript:`:

```
<div onclick="javascript:location.href='http://yoursite.com';">Content</div>
```

Comment: а что должно произойти по клику? У меня 404 ошибка)

Answer (score 3):

Делать ссылки на JS - это уже неправильный семантический подход. Ссылки должны индексироваться и быть доступны скринридерами. Да и зачем усложнять жизнь с джаваскриптом, когда есть возможность реализации на нативном HTML.

Делай так:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class='block'>
  <div class='block__content'>Контент</div>
</a>
```

Но так как ссылка - строчный элемент, внутри него неправильно всовывать блочные элементы. Поэтому лучше сделать ссылку элементом блока, и потом натянуть ее поверх остального содержимого блока:

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.block__link {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <div class='block__content'>Контент</div>
  <a href='#' class='block__ghostLink'>Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

По клику, например.

```
$('div#go_to_yandex').on('click', function(event) {
    window.location.href = 'https://ya.ru';
});
```

или без Query:

```
document.getElementById('go_to_yandex').onclick = function(event) {
    window.location.href = 'https://ya.ru';
};
```

Comment: этот способ не работает в некоторых браузерах. Например firefox. Нужно использовать фейковый "а" вместо.

Comment: @nick_n_a неправда, в Firefox работает

Comment: @nick_n_a не может быть. везде работает

Comment: @nick_n_a обновил ответ

Comment: @nick_n_a, что конкретно может не работать в ff? изменение location?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте блоку событие `onClick="window.location.href=''`, в `href` добавьте адрес ссылки

Comment: этот способ не работает в некоторых браузерах.

Comment: @nick_n_a например?

Comment: В firefox не работает.

Comment: @nick_n_a работает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560633/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-location-href

Comment: @nick_n_a а при чём тут это?

Comment: Присваивание href не срабатывает иногда (не открывает страницу). Я часто с этим сталкивался. Через `createElement("a")` всегда срабатывает.

Comment: @nick_n_a зато я не сталкивался ни разу. Покажите пример (без ифреймов, в вопросе про них ни слова); вот мой пример в моём Firefox стабильно работает всегда https://jsfiddle.net/r9z6L3be/